# Setting UnobtrusiveValidationMode to None doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, unobtrusive-validation

Here we go again.

Another question on Microsoft's UnobtrusiveValidationMode.

So here is my problem.

## Problem 1

On post back, the message shows up but the data is submitted.... odd (not on all sites)

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
```

To clarify, none means use the 4.0 validation and the code to write to the database is still executed on a submit.

## Problem 2

If I decide to use the .net 4.5 validation, JQuery is only loaded when needed.

- I have a UI that requires JQuery
- If I put a ScriptManager in the Masterpage, JQuery is loaded **twice** on form pages

So is there a way to either

- Make UnobtrusiveValidationMode **not** process the information when set to None
- Not have JQuery loaded 2x if I did UnobtrusiveValidationMode on form pages

Comment: Try setting UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to "flase" instead of "None"

Comment: That does not work. Upon further investigation it has something to do with Context.RewritePath in my global.aspx file. I check to see if a file exists, if it does not - i rewrite the path. for some reason its effecting the validation.

Comment: @EricHarms  I have a similar problem. The UnobrusiveValidationMode is set to None but the data in the Submit code is processed.  But I don't have global.aspx in my project.  Did you ever find what else could be causing this problem?  And is there another place where my Global.aspx could be?